# Should I always use stripslashes for _POST _GET and _COOKIE variables

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

I'm really confused when I read about the function `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` in PHP.

Everywhere it's said that the function is deprecated ([example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)).

But what is the default behaviour in PHP 5.3? I used to check, if `magic_quotes_gpc` in on and stripped all slashes if that was the case, right at the beginning of my script for all `POST`, `GET` and `COOKIE` variables, so that I don't get confused.

But if I shouldn't check for added slashes using `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`, always removing slashes would result in wrong data, if no slashes are added by PHP 5.3.

I have the same confusion with [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sybase.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-sybase)

At the moment `magic_quotes_gpc` is on on my server (PHP 5.2.17), so I need to remove the slashes. But how should I handle this to be prepared for future PHP versions?

Can I somehow set the default values in future during the runtime at the beginning of my script? But what are the default values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `get_magic_quotes_gpc` function isn't deprecated, it's the `magic_quotes_gpc` config setting that's deprecated.

The solution is to not use the `magic_quotes_gpc` config setting on your own server, but also use `get_magic_quotes_gpc` if you want to write robust code that will run on servers that do have the deprecated `magic_quotes_gpc` setting turned on.

In other words:

- Turn off `magic_quotes_gpc` in your config.
- Wherever you currently use `stripslashes`, change it to only call `stripslashes` if `get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1`.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have write-access to the config files a that server. I wrote an own function that checks for magic_quotes_gpc(). But you say the adding slashes is the default behaviour in PHP >5.3? Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: No, adding slashes is no the default behavior unless `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled. You don't really need to write your own version of `get_magic_quotes_gpc`, it's not deprecated.

Comment: I started using the function "filter_input_array()". It seems that this function automatically removes the slashes in the values. I really don't get the Warning text given on http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php . Is it the default behaviour of sanitize filter to remove the slashes? Why aren't slashes in arrays removed? For example `<input type="text" name="name[3][to&quot;ll]" value="&quot;">` gives `name[3][to\"ll]: "` as output. So, for the value the slashes are removed but not for the keys. But I couldn't find a description for this behaviour in the PHP manual,...

Comment: @Sven I'm not sure, I haven't used the `filter_input` stuff much... I usually filter stuff by type conversion or regex.

Comment: Though I think one may also need to use stripslashes() on a string that was previously converted with addslashes().

Comment: Just spend two hours bughunting, turned out excessive stripslashes() on $_REQUEST was the cause. Your comment was the solution. This should be part of the PHP documentation.